# Unable to update the Vuex store and retrieve array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex

I'm dispatching an array of objects to the Veux store and trying to get the data using "getters" from Vuex. It returns undefined. It is however working for a boolean variable in the same Vuex. For the array, it is not giving a proper result

I am using Vuex to update an array of objects across vue components.

I am dispatching the array of objects

committing the array through "actions"

setting and updating the value through "mutations"

Declaring the array through "state"

finally, from the Vue component, accessing the array through "getters"

I expect Vuex to return the array of objects when I access using "getters"

The store code is as given below

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    
      loading: false,
      compoData: []
  },

  mutations: {
 
    setLoading(state, payload) {
      state.loading = payload
    },

    setCompoData(state, payload) {
       state.compoData = payload.data
     }
  },


actions: {
    
    setLoading({
      commit
    }, payload) {
      commit('setLoading', payload)
    },

    setCompoData({
      commit
    }, payload) {
      commit('setCompoData', payload)
    },

  },
  
  
  getters: {
    
    loading(state) {
      return state.loading
    },
    
    compoaData(state){
      return state.compoData
    }

  }
})
```

Vue component code is as given below. I am dispatching the array of objects "compoData" from the component to the store

```js
  someFunction(){
            
    .....
    some code
    .....
    this.$store.dispatch('setLoading',false)
    this.$store.dispatch('setCompoData',{data:this.compoData})
           
            
        },
```

Getting the values from store

```js
       
       
       gettingCompoData(){
            console.log(this.$store.getters.compoData)
            
        },
```

Though it works fine with the computed variable "loading", it does not work with the "compoData" array of objects .

I tested it with the below function

```js
test(){
    console.log(this.compoData, this.loading);
    this.$store.dispatch('setCompoData',{data:this.compoData})
    console.log(this.$store.getters.compoData, this.$store.getters.loading)
},
```

And this is the screenshot of the result I got this [log result from the "test" function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3CYI.png)

It is clear that I am not sending an undefined array. But what I am getting from the store getters is undefined. Strangely, it is working for the boolean variable "loading" and it does return a valid result. I'm baffled as to why it does not return the array of objects. please help me out...

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, most likely your payload is undefined (of whatever the value "it does not work" means).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kursus. I have edited the question by including a screenshot of the  log. please see that and let me know if you have any clue what might be happening in my case. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo.
in store you defined a getter `compoaData` and when getting values from store you're looking for `compoData`

Comment: Thank you so much fila. :) . OMG! I wasted about a couple of hours or so trying to figure out what was wrong. i totally overlooked it. I truly appreciate your time. Thanks again.

Comment: no worries, typos are the worst kind of bugs hahaha

Comment: Seriously! I couldn't agree more. And now it works like  a charm :)